# Advice needed - Jersy or Spring for google cloud technologies?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

We have few services on Google App Engine(GAE) and few on Google Container Engine (GKE).
The one on GKE is a sort of indexing service RESTful API and runs in background once triggered. It is an RESTful endpoint developed using Jersy.

***my confusion and question is***, Is migrating this to spring boot beneficial ? I see advantages of spring as DI, aop, exception handling etc. plus I have worked on it before inclines me more towards choosing spring :p

In contrast , if continue using jesrsy, we have to adopt guice for DI and I don't have much idea if we can do anything sort of aop and security (maybe using filters etc)

Please let me know your views/experiences on this.
Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use `Guice` if you keep using `Jersey`, `Spring` integrates very well with `Jersey` even before `Spring Boot` was released.

`Spring Boot` provides a `Jersey` starter that makes integration easier: `spring-boot-starter-jersey`

And if you are curious, I published a while back a post about [Spring Boot, Jersey, Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for putting your insight! My question is - isn't using spring boot alone will save the complexity and give all the advantages of jersy as well?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot helps with managing a lot of dependencies that otherwise you would need to spend the time to do. It also auto-configure beans based on libraries found in the classpath while making it easy to drop when you need to explicitly define them.

Comment: Thank you so much..it really helps!